# 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, face-recognition

Good afternoon, I have such a code for face recognition. I found it on GitHub,but there is a problem with attribute 'predict_proba'. I already found that model.predict_proba should be replaced with model.predict, but in my case it falls into a different error.

Here is my piece of code that uses this function:

```
def face_predict(face, image):    
    if K.image_data_format() == 'th' and image.shape != (1, 3, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE):
        image = resize_image(image)
        image = image.reshape((1, 3, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))   
    elif K.image_data_format() == 'tf' and image.shape != (1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3):
        image = resize_image(image)
        image = image.reshape((1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))                    
    
    image = image.astype('float32')
    image /= 255
    
    result = face.model.predict_proba(image)
    print('result:', result)
    
    result = face.model.predict_classes(image)        

    return result[0]
```

When I change model.predict_proba to model.predict I get the following error in the temporary file:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 64, 64, 3), found shape=(None, 255, 3)
```

Is it possible in this case to replace it so that it returns the result as expected?

Comment: What's the shape of `image` right before you pass it to `.predict()`?

Comment: @Djinn I recently started doing face recognition, in what way is the "shape of the image"? The size or how is it served there?

Comment: `print(image.shape)`

Comment: @Djinn I use a model generated by a neural network, and the images are loaded directly from a dataset in which I have 1000 photos of my face.

Comment: You said you do this: `result = face.model.predict(image)`. So what is the shape of `image`? The error is saying you're passing an image with shape `(255, 3)`, which does not represent an image nor does it match what the model is expecting `(64, 64, 3)`.

Comment: @Djinn I looked at my code again, but I still couldn't figure out why the image is loaded into shape (255, 3). 
I have uploaded my code to Git, could you please take a look.
[Link](https://github.com/SzarekhSwift/My-Face-Recognition)

Comment: **def face_predict** is in the file
face_train.py and used for face recognition in face_recognition.py